# RequireSSL fails on Url with Querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl

I use this code which is taken from MVC futures and attach the Attribute RequireSsl to an action.
It works with simple Url like http://localhost/de/Account/Login, but if I have a querystring, the questionmark gets url encoded and the request fails.

http://localhost/de/Account/Login?test=omg redirects to 
https://localhost/de/Account/Login%3Ftest=omg.  Anybody got this working?

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class RequireSslAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public RequireSslAttribute()
    {
        Redirect = true;
    }

    public bool Redirect { get; set; }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //Validate.IsNotNull(filterContext, "filterContext");

        if (!Configuration.EnableSSL) return;

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            // request is not SSL-protected, so throw or redirect
            if (Redirect)
            {
                // form new URL
                UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder
                {
                    Scheme = "https",
                    Host = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host,
                    // use the RawUrl since it works with URL Rewriting
                    Path = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl
                };
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(builder.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Access forbidden. The requested resource requires an SSL connection.");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed

```
 UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder
                {
                    Scheme = "https",
                    Host = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host,
                    // use the RawUrl since it works with URL Rewriting
                    Path = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl
                };
```

To

```
                    UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder
                {
                    Scheme = "https",
                    Host = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host,
                    Path = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.LocalPath,
                    Query = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery

                };
```

I dont use UrlRewriting right now, thats why I guess this is safe for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder
{
    Scheme = "https",
    Host = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host,
    Path = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path,
    Query = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.ToString ()
};
```